# JQuery Validate hide error container

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the JQuery Validate Plugin and I have some issue with the error container. The setup is:

```
<div class="form-row">
            <label class="span3">First name</label>
            <input data-ref-error="firstnameErrorLabel" class="span4" type="text" id="firstname" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row-error" style="display:none;" id="firstnameErrorLabel">
            <div class="span4 text-error">Please enter a first name</div>
        </div>

$('#form').validate({
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
              error.appendTo($('#' + element.data('ref-error')));
              $('#' + element.data('ref-error')).show();
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
```

The problem now is, that the errorContainer won't hide again once an error occurs. I need the whole div to be hidden again once there is no error. The problem is that I cannot use a generic error container because the plugin is used within a larger codebase and the error container may be a span or something different in another case (in this case it's a div).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

One huge problem is that your input element does not contain a `name` attribute.  This is **mandatory** in order for this plugin to function properly.

```
<input name="firstname" data-ref-error="firstnameErrorLabel" class="span4" type="text" id="firstname" required/>
```

> The problem is that I cannot use a generic error container because the plugin is used within a larger codebase and the error container may be a span or something different in another case (in this case it's a div).

It's best to allow the plugin to control the error messages automatically.  The plugin provides [a toolbox full of options](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) to achieve any desired HTML structure.

Simply change your error container into a `div` using the `errorElement` option.  Then modify `errorPlacement` so the message is placed inside your other `div` and the desired classes are applied.

```
$('#form').validate({
    errorElement: 'div',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        element.parent().next('div').html(error);
        error.addClass('span4 text-error');
    },
    messages: {
        firstname: {
            required: "Please enter a first name"
        }
    }
    ....
```

The following demo shows the plugin dynamically creating your desired structure.  Tweak as needed...

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/2ckokp1L/**

Your starting markup:

```
<div class="form-row-error" id="firstnameErrorLabel"></div>
```

DOM structure dynamically created by plugin:

```
<div class="form-row-error" id="firstnameErrorLabel">
    <div id="firstname-error" class="error span4 text-error">Please enter a first name</div>
</div>
```